# Deleting records using Mongomapper in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongomapper

I'm enjoying the pretty amazing MongoDB in Rails by using Mongomapper but I am having problems removing records.

What is the accepted way of removing records, and also removing a whole document?

I tried using Stuff.destroy_all but it seems to crash the web server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, that's not well documented. I'm opening an issue for that.

See the [class methods](https://github.com/jnunemaker/mongomapper/blob/b965105ea203368234636df21c64f05358a467fb/lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/querying.rb#L43-57) and [instance methods](https://github.com/jnunemaker/mongomapper/blob/b965105ea203368234636df21c64f05358a467fb/lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/querying.rb#L137-143).

```
my_doc.destroy    # fires callbacks
my_doc.delete     # no callbacks, just removes it from the database
MyDoc.destroy_all # fires callbacks, shouldn't crash...!
MyDoc.delete_all  # no callbacks
MyDoc.destroy("b965105ea203368234636df2", "368234636df21c64f05358a4")
MyDoc.delete("b965105ea203368234636df2", "368234636df21c64f05358a4")
```

Answer (score 1):

Yea, I have stumbled and bumbled quite a few times deleting stuff in MongoMapper. This technique seems to work as well:

```
MessageLog.destroy_all(:created_at.gte => @start_time)
```

Took me a while to figure out why `delete_all` was sooooo much faster than `destroy_all` :-p

Answer (score 0):

And `delete_all` and `destroy_all` also work as Plucky methods, so you can do things like:

```
MyDoc.where(status: 'unneeded').delete_all
MyDoc.where(status: 'unneeded').destroy_all
```

Depending on if you want to avoid callbacks (`delete_all`) or execute them (`destroy_all`).